# Conditional Probability problem on single coin toss

Tags: conditional-probability

A fair coin is tossed 4 times. Provided that at least 2 heads occurred within the 4 tossings, what's the probability that at least one tail also occurred?

Comment: How many equally probably ways of getting at least two heads?  How many of these do not have any tails?

Comment: This should be a routine application of definitions of conditional probability.  Where could you have gotten stuck?

Comment: If you really have no idea how to start, just list the $16$ possible outcomes and count.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{cccc}
H & H & H & H
\end{array} \\
\left.\begin{array}{cccc}
H & H & H & t \\
H & H & t & H \\
H & t & H & H \\
t & H & H & H
\end{array} \right\} \text{ 3 heads in 4 tosses} \\
\left.\begin{array}{cccc}
H & H & t & t \\
H & t & H & t \\
t & H & H & t \\
H & t & t & H \\
t & H & t & H \\
t & t & H & H
\end{array} \right\} \text{ 2 heads in 4 tosses}
\end{array}
$$
There are $6$ ways to get $2$ heads and $4$ ways to get $3$ heads, and just one way to get $4$ heads. Thus $11$ ways to get at least $2$ heads. In $10$ of those $11$ ways, there is at least $1$ tail.